# Passport.js append custom parameter to authorizationURL-call

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

Is there any way to append custom parameters to an passport.js Oauth2 call?

The call is made to an URL build as follows:

**authorizationURL**?response_type=code&redirect_uri=**callbackURL**&scope=**scope**&client_id=**clientID**

Is there a way to alter this URL and append "&myparameter=myvalue"

So the wished result is
**authorizationURL**?response_type=code&redirect_uri=**callbackURL**&scope=**scope**&client_id=**clientID**&myparameter=**myvalue**

(All Bold Parameters are specified below:)

---

*Long Story:*

Defining a Strategy (e.G. Amazon Strategy) as follows:

```
passport.use(new AmazonStrategy({
            clientID: config.amazon.clientID,
            clientSecret: config.amazon.clientSecret,
            callbackURL: config.amazon.callbackURL,
            passReqToCallback: true,
            authorizationURL: 'https://eu.account.amazon.com/ap/oa?',
            tokenURL: 'https://api.sandbox.amazon.de/auth/o2/token'
        }
```

And the request

```
app.get('/oauth/amazon', passport.authenticate('amazon', {
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        scope: ['profile postal_code']
    }));
```

The callback similar to the request!

***Actual Question***:

How to append "&myparameter=myvalue"

Comment: Try appending it directly to the url, like `callbackURL: config.amazon.callbackURL + '?myparameter=myvalue'`

Comment: yes i did this. You need to specify the `authorizationURL: config.amazon.callbackURL + "?myparameter=myvalue&response_type=code&`
Otherwise you end up with two `?` and the URL is missinterpreted.
This adds the Parameter `?response_type` which is not used.
So i was wondering if there is a "propper way" of doing it